# Creating a stored procedure to update a row in a SQL database using data from the previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Good afternoon all,

I have a database which is used to track production on an assembly line.

Effectively the finished product will show each `stage` of the production line and the serial number of what is currently in it.

I have created a stored procedure to retrieve and display this data, but where I am struggling is to move a machine from `stage 1` to `stage 2` and `stage 2` to `stage 3` etc... The table is very simple, it contains the following rows:

```
Stage_ID (PK, int, not null)
Build_ID(FK, int, null)
```

Effectively, I want to build a stored procedure to move the value of `Build_ID` where `Stage_ID = 1` to `Stage_ID = 2`.

Any idea how I would do this?

Thanks

Comment: can you show us what you've got so far?

Comment: What tables are the columns on?

Comment: Please be more clear.

Comment: For example, I can do this using raw SQL by doing: update tblBuildStages set Build_ID = 10 where Stage_ID = 2 ... But I will not know the build number when in production, I need to pull the build number from the previous "stage" and put that value in to stage 2... I hope that helps to clarify

Comment: so you want to do like update tblBuildStages set Build_ID = select max(Stage_ID) +1 Where Stage_Id = 1 ?

Comment: columns must belong to tables or views, I'm asking what the table or view is called. That makes it easier to write the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update stageTable
set build_id = (select build_id from stageTable where stage_id = 1)
where stage_id = 2
```

if you need it as a procedure you could do something like this

```
create procedure sp_moveStage(@from int, @to int)
as 

update stageTable
set build_id = (select build_id from stageTable where stage_id = @from)
where stage_id = @to
```

and execute it with

```
exec sp_moveStage 1, 2
```

Comment: @guyh92, your database schema is very denormalized. (+1 for single statement) but what if there are multiple rows with `stage_id = 1`?

Comment: @Jodrell Stage ID is primary, in logical terms there can only ever be one machine in one stage, so that can never happen. This will effectively overwrite the current record for Stage_id = 2... I accept your point though.

Comment: @jhinkley thanks that's ideal. I would vote you up but I am a new member!

Answer (score 0):

Keys are not mutable, so you would have to insert the new row and delete the old row.  Not an ideal design you have there.

P.S. If StageID is the PK as you have it, you can have only one row where StageID = 2:

```
 Stage_ID (PK, int, not null)   <<<---
 Build_ID(FK, int, null)
```

What you want is a table like this:

```
  create table process
  (id int primary key,
   buildid int not null,
   stage  int not null,
   entrydatetime datetime,
   exitdatetime datetime
   )
```

showing when a build enters and leaves a processing stage. Or you could derive the time the stage was exited by assuming the entry time of the next stage if the stage values are sortable sequentially in a meaningful way.

In any event, you don't want to make a changing value like "stage in the process" be a PK.  Stage is a changing value, a property or attribute of a build, whereas a PK is an immutable entity identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work.
Step 1 - get the max stage id for your build id and set it to a variable.
Step 2 - add a record to the table.  The stage id will be the variable from Step 1, plus 1.

Answer (score 0):

erm,

```
DECLARE @Build_ID int;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

SELECT @Build_ID = Build_ID FROM SomeTable WHERE Stage_ID = 1;

UPDATE SomeTable SET Build_ID = @Build_ID WHERE Stage_ID = 2;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```